# What can I do to find the crash reason

Tags: 18.04, system, log

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04, it crashes about once a week. Sometimes while watching video sometime or just web-browsing. I check the system log and kernel log they don't have any strange output at the crash time, last output before crashing is something normal being outputed several times a day.

And I not able to use <kbd>Ctrl+ALT+F3</kbd> to enter virtual terminal or `REISUB reset` , every time I had to restart my PC by powerbutton. How can I find where the problems are?

Comment: Try looking in the `/var/crash/` folder.

Comment: `journalctl -b -1 -e` will show the last of the logs of the previous boot. Also, consider CPU overheating, power supply problems. They appear as instant OFF, and don't get logged. If multiple reboot logs (see `man journalctl`) show unrelated, random entries just before reboor, suspect hardware.

Comment: @waltinator Thanks. I'll check when next crash happens(I hope not though), thermal and power are fine I'm sure.

Comment: You don't have to wait for the next crash. `journalctl --list-boots` will list boots (and their time/date), and you can adjust the `-b #` of `journalctl -b -1 -e` to select one.

Comment: @waltinator Great, I found the last output logs and posted on another question. I don't know are they relevant to the crash or not. Would you take a look? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1068857/help-understand-last-output-logs-before-crashing