# Help understand last output logs before crashing

Tags: crash, log

There are the logs before my PC crashed(Ubuntu 18.04), they seem to do something with `Albert`, what do these logs mean?

```
Aug 24 00:50:08 t480s systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
Aug 24 00:50:31 t480s nautilus[5186]: ../../../../gobject/gsignal.c:2641: instance '0x55970244fe40' 
Aug 24 00:50:31 t480s nautilus[5186]: ../../../../gobject/gsignal.c:2641: instance '0x55970244fe40' 
Aug 24 00:57:24 t480s plank.desktop[3518]: [4042:4059:0824/005724.078476:ERROR:service_manager_conte
Aug 24 01:02:41 t480s systemd[1]: Started Run anacron jobs.
Aug 24 01:02:41 t480s anacron[25874]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2018-08-24
Aug 24 01:02:41 t480s anacron[25874]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
Aug 24 01:07:46 t480s albert.desktop[3318]: 01:07:46 [INFO] Start indexing Chrome bookmarks.
Aug 24 01:07:46 t480s albert.desktop[3318]: 01:07:46 [INFO] Indexed 145 Chrome bookmarks.
Aug 24 01:08:45 t480s albert.desktop[3318]: 01:08:45 [INFO] Start indexing Chrome bookmarks.
Aug 24 01:08:45 t480s albert.desktop[3318]: 01:08:45 [INFO] Indexed 145 Chrome bookmarks.
Aug 24 01:09:02 t480s org.gnome.Shell.desktop[3038]: Window manager warning: Invalid WM_TRANSIENT_FO
Aug 24 01:10:59 t480s albert.desktop[3318]: 01:10:59 [INFO] Start indexing Chrome bookmarks.
Aug 24 01:10:59 t480s albert.desktop[3318]: 01:10:59 [INFO] Indexed 145 Chrome bookmarks.
Aug 24 01:11:02 t480s albert.desktop[3318]: 01:11:02 [INFO] Start indexing Chrome bookmarks.
Aug 24 01:11:02 t480s albert.desktop[3318]: 01:11:02 [INFO] Indexed 145 Chrome bookmarks.
Aug 24 01:11:05 t480s albert.desktop[3318]: 01:11:05 [INFO] Start indexing Chrome bookmarks.
Aug 24 01:11:05 t480s albert.desktop[3318]: 01:11:05 [INFO] Indexed 145 Chrome bookmarks.
Aug 24 01:11:11 t480s albert.desktop[3318]: 01:11:11 [INFO] Start indexing Chrome bookmarks.
Aug 24 01:11:11 t480s albert.desktop[3318]: 01:11:11 [INFO] Indexed 145 Chrome bookmarks.
Aug 24 01:17:01 t480s CRON[26779]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Aug 24 01:17:01 t480s CRON[26780]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Aug 24 01:17:01 t480s CRON[26779]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Aug 24 01:17:42 t480s albert.desktop[3318]: 01:17:42 [INFO] Start indexing Chrome bookmarks.
Aug 24 01:17:42 t480s albert.desktop[3318]: 01:17:42 [INFO] Indexed 145 Chrome bookmarks.
Aug 24 01:19:34 t480s albert.desktop[3318]: 01:19:34 [INFO] Start indexing Chrome bookmarks.
Aug 24 01:19:34 t480s albert.desktop[3318]: 01:19:34 [INFO] Indexed 145 Chrome bookmarks.
Aug 24 01:20:18 t480s albert.desktop[3318]: 01:20:18 [INFO] Start indexing Chrome bookmarks.
Aug 24 01:20:18 t480s albert.desktop[3318]: 01:20:18 [INFO] Indexed 145 Chrome bookmarks.
Aug 24 01:20:48 t480s albert.desktop[3318]: 01:20:48 [INFO] Start indexing Chrome bookmarks.
Aug 24 01:20:48 t480s albert.desktop[3318]: 01:20:48 [INFO] Indexed 145 Chrome bookmarks.
```

Comment: By the looks of things you seem to have albert launcher installed and it is indexing your chrome bookmarks. There's nothing worrying in there, although the indexing frequency seems excessive. To see what has been crashing, look in /var/crash and read up on apport to get a better understanding of what you will find in there. NOTE: apport might be disabled by default on your system.