Reboot shortcut keyboard not working after freeze
I have a PC dual boot Windows-Ubuntu. Recently the boot partition of Ubuntu stopped working and I installed a new Ubuntu system. Now my Ubuntu system freezes more frequently than before and after that the shortcut keyboard (REISUB or alt-SysRq-B) do not work. I'm forced to shutdown the system with the power button. Also the shortcut works fine when the pc is not frozen.
My Ubuntu system is Ubuntu 24.04 LTS

I think it is important to find out why your system freezes, one possible way is to run journalctl -f in a terminal, resize it so you can work, then press ALT+Spacebar+T and mark always on top and then wait for freeze. As for reboot there are some ways described here https://askubuntu.com/questions/11002/alt-sysrq-reisub-doesnt-reboot-my-laptop/334292#334292

I tried to do it but the ALT+Spacebar+T does not work

If you minimize everything except the terminal click in it so that it is active then push ALT+Spacebar you will see a dialog openng up, choose Always on top.

This post has better answes to how to find out the problem https://askubuntu.com/questions/1068720/what-can-i-do-to-find-the-crash-reason

now is much more clear thank you really much

you are welcome, when you find out more you should search, maybe you find the answer already given otherwise if you need help you should make a new question with the info you gathered,

I checked indeed and I believe the problem is with the alimentation since the battery is exhausted. Didn't realise that.
