24.04 crashing randomly to login screen
I have an i5 7600k + 32 GB RAM + RX 480 GPU. Ubuntu or GNOME will crash a few times a day or crash sometimes more frequently. It goes back to the login screen but everything is closed. Fresh install of 24.04. Seems like a GNOME problem since it takes me back to login. I dual boot with Windows 11 and it runs fine.

There can be many reasons to crashes, pls read this and all the links that are included in it https://askubuntu.com/questions/1068720/what-can-i-do-to-find-the-crash-reason and then post with relevant info so that someone can help.

I'm facing the same problem here. Installed 24.04, and sometimes when i access contexts menus (mainly from Eclipse IDE), my ubuntu crashes and goes back to login screen with everything closed as well. /var/crash and journalctl does not tell me anything. I'm think this is related to sort of GUI (Gnome) problems. I disabled all gnome extensions and now it seems to be fine.

No idea why, but the issue resolved itself.

Have you ever tried to disable Wayland on gdm3.conf ?
Just uncomment WaylandEnable and set to false (/etc/gdm3/custom.conf)
Next, restart gdm3 (systemctl restart gdm3)
