After upgrade to 24.04 LTS, frequent crashing when unlocking
I recently upgraded from 22.04 LTS to 24.04 LTS. After the upgrade, I had some difficulty related to my mouse cursor, which caused instantaneous crashing the moment I signed in. I was able to resolve this, and things are now mostly working properly, but I am frequently encountering a crash that looks pretty much the same occurring when I unlock the workstation. It's by no means every time, but just randomly, I'll bring my laptop out of sleep mode, enter my password, and BAM, white screen, tiny unhappy computer logo, generic text. "Oh no! Something has gone wrong. A problem has occurred and the system can't recover." The only option it gives me is to immediately terminate my login session. When I do that, the white screen goes away and I can see all my running programs briefly before they are all terminated. The error dialog that comes up doesn't seem to have any details at all about the actual cause of the error. Is there a way to dig deeper and find out what exactly it thinks is such an unrecoverable error? Is this perhaps another facet of the mouse cursor adventure??

Probably this will help and also open all the links in it. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1068720/what-can-i-do-to-find-the-crash-reason

Did you ever figure anything out here? I have the exact same symptoms as you. PC is sleeping, I go to unlock, and then get the crash screen. I've been looking at the system logs now and then and nothing really stands out to me. At least we know we're not alone I guess.

It's been months now, and I'm not dealing with that any more. I think it was switching to KDE that resolved the issue, but honestly my memory is fuzzy of what exactly was going on back then. Sorry!

Hmm, actually, there is a faint memory trying to unlock itself of a specific technical change... Shoot, I can't remember though. Maybe something to do with Synaptics drivers??

Man, I am so sorry I didn't think to come back here and write it up when my memory was fresh. :-(
