UBUNTU 24.04LTS stops working several times all of a sudden!
I have recently installed UBUNTU 24.04 LTS on my old laptop hp Pavilion tx1000 (Spec: AMD Turion™ 64 X2 Mobile Technology TL-56 × 2, RAM 4 GB, Graphic NV4E, SSD 120 GB).
The laptop has stopped responding while using it several times, all of a sudden.
Sometimes everything just freezes and no key works and mouse pointer doesn't move, and sometimes the screen turns black and never turns back on.
I guessed it may be related to touchpad or Firefox, and I stopped using both of them but the problem didn't stopped.
Also I tried to monitor the resources by System Monitor, Most of the time neither the CPU is fully occupied, nor the RAM.
I had a 14.04LTS on this laptop several years ago and cannot remember such a problem with that; and before this OS, windows 10 was installed and worked well.

Welcome to the forum, Pls read this https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers, then go here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1068720/what-can-i-do-to-find-the-crash-reason and also read all the links. When you aquire more info. pls update your question with that.

For me its a random freeze where sound works, I did an experiment with teams running with screen sharing waiting for the freeze to happen, as I said, all sound devices and camera devices work, the screen share worked, but even the other person saw my screen was frozen :(

I had the same issue on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS. A quick workaround is to open tty1 by pressing Ctrl + Alt + F1. This will take you to a login page, where you can continue using the system for the time being. While this isn't a full solution, it helps to regain control temporarily until the community releases a proper fix. Let's hope for a more permanent resolution soon!

I had this issue with Ubuntu 24.04 as well. I did NOT have this issue with Ubuntu 23.10. After doing several things such as reinstalling Gnome Desktop, installing the NVIDIA driver from their website, and switching to the Nouveau NVIDIA driver, none of which fixed the issue, I discovered it was an incompatibility with Wayland and the NVIDIA driver. Switching to X11 solved the problem.
To switch to X11 from Wayland:

Open /etc/gdm3/custom.conf as root
Uncomment the line #WaylandEnable=false by removing the #
Save the file
Reboot


For me it's the opposite on Nvidia, where Wayland works fine but X11 (which I need) freezes constantly.

It is happening to my computer with Ubuntu 24.04 and I don't even have a NVidia nor AMD card.

I switched to X11, still freezes randomly :(
I feel this problem needs to be looked deeper :/
